sum case with left join
I would like to count the waves available (LEFT OUT JOIN). My problem is that I also have another LEFT OUTER JOIN on invitations.
The idea is to have all the stats from the same SQL request. Stats from invitations and stats from waves.
An event has many waves
An event has many invitations
CREATE TABLE public.events (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    uuid uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
    name character varying NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.invitations (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    uuid uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    event_id bigint NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.invitation_waves (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    uuid uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    wavable_type character varying,
    wavable_id bigint,
    scheduled_at timestamp(6) without time zone
);

I have tested 2 options
Option 1
SELECT CAST(sum((case when (waves.id IS NOT NULL) then 1 else 0 end)) AS INTEGER) as total_waves
FROM "events"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "waves" ON "waves"."wavable_type" = 'Event' AND
                                               "waves"."wavable_id" = "events"."id"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "invitations" ON "invitations"."event_id" = "events"."id"
WHERE "events"."uuid" = 'XXX'
GROUP BY "events"."id"

-> It gives me the number of invitations created if above the number of waves
Option 2 (with DISTINCT)
SELECT CAST(sum(DISTINCT(case when (waves.id IS NOT NULL) then 1 else 0 end)) AS INTEGER) as total_waves
FROM "events"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "waves" ON "waves"."wavable_type" = 'Event' AND
                                               "waves"."wavable_id" = "events"."id"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "invitations" ON "invitations"."event_id" = "events"."id"
WHERE "events"."uuid" = 'XXX'
GROUP BY "events"."id"

-> Always returns me 1 which is, I suppose, the number of events matching the request (I've scoped it with the uuid).
Not having the DISTINCT is actually multiplying the correct sum by the number of waves.
Having the DISTINCT restrict the entire sum to the number of waves.
Option 3 (sub select) ✅
I'm currently trying this option based on this answer.
It is working but I'm concerned about the dependency between GROUP BY and the selected columns from the LEFT OUTER JOIN.
SELECT CAST(sum((case
                     when (invitations.status = 4 or invitations.status = 5 or invitations.status = 6) then 1
                     else 0 end)) AS INTEGER) as total_validated,
       total_waves,
       waves_scheduled
FROM "events"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "invitations" ON "invitations"."event_id" = "events"."id"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT distinct on (wavable_id)
                                 wavable_id                                                                                      as event_id,
                                 CAST(sum((case when (invitation_waves.id IS NOT NULL) then 1 else 0 end)) AS INTEGER)           as total_waves,
                                 CAST(sum((case when (invitation_waves.scheduled_at IS NOT NULL) then 1 else 0 end)) AS INTEGER) as waves_scheduled
                          FROM invitation_waves
                          WHERE wavable_type = 'Event'
                          GROUP BY 1 
                          ORDER BY wavable_id) as "wave_stats" on "wave_stats"."event_id" = "events"."id"
WHERE "events"."uuid" = '1ee5ec72-6f3c-404c-871c-5c5724f6a1ed'
GROUP BY "events"."id", total_waves, waves_scheduled

Final version
Thanks to @Thorsten, I pick an hybrid version between WITH and direct LEFT JOIN.
Invitation table was too big (and also joined to another to use a WITH and FILTER I suppose and I needed to GROUP BY every generated column from the with.
So here is my final version
WITH "wave_stats" AS (SELECT wavable_id                                                 as event_id,
                             COUNT(DISTINCT id)                                         AS total_waves,
                             COUNT(DISTINCT id) FILTER (where scheduled_at IS NOT NULL) AS waves_scheduled
                      FROM "waves"
                      WHERE "waves"."wavable_type" = 'Event'
                      GROUP BY "waves"."wavable_id")
SELECT events.*,
       CAST(COUNT(invitations.id) AS INTEGER) AS total_invitations, CAST (sum((case
    when (invitations.status = 4 or invitations.status = 5 or invitations.status = 6) then 1
    else 0 end)) AS INTEGER) as total_validated, case when wave_stats.waves_scheduled is null then 0 else wave_stats.waves_scheduled
end,
       case when wave_stats.total_waves is null then 0 else wave_stats.total_waves
end FROM "events"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "invitations" ON "invitations"."event_id" = "events"."id"
         LEFT JOIN wave_stats ON wave_stats.event_id = events.id
GROUP BY "events"."id", "total_waves", "waves_scheduled"


A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

distinct isn't a function, it's a set quantifier. Skip those extra pair of parentheses.

I've added the creation table. Thank you for the clarification for distinct. SQL request is not failing without, you were right. But I think it is not solving the problem.

I've also added the 3rd option I'm working on with a sub-select. Still not able to make it work for now @jarlh

Why are you using SUM(CASE... instead of just using COUNT(DISTINCT waves.id)?

@JohnH because I cannot count twice with different conditions isn't it?

It might just be my opinion but I do not find your question clear enough to answer without a data sample + expected result. On a related note, sentences like "An event has many waves An event has many invitations" are more often than not translated into foreign keys, which your tables lack. That too could make things clearer.

I just skipped the foreign keys because I thought it was not helpful here since column names are self explanatory.
Of course there are foreign keys.
I've added more description about the expected result.

You're making observations and expressing concerns, without actually asking anything. If it's about performance, attach DDL for tables and indexes involved along with explain(analyze,verbose,buffers,settings) for the statements you're testing. If it's about validity of the results, add example input and expected output vs what you're getting instead. There's no INNER variant of a LEFT JOIN, OUTER is always implied - if that's about verbosity, why not SELECT ALL and FROM ONLY tbl/FROM tbl* too

That whole sum(case...) looks like a long, long way of doing a count(waves.id)::int: "count ( "any" ) → bigint Computes the number of input rows in which the input value is not null." The sum(DISTINCT(case when (waves.id IS NOT NULL) then 1 else 0 end)) always returns 1 because you only allow two values in, a 0 and a 1, and distinct discards all their duplicates. Unsurprisingly, these sum up to a 1. You can only get a 0 if all waves.id are null.

You want to count invitations and waves per event. For this to happen you join the invitations and waves to an event, but this gives you a cartesian product, i.e. for an event with, say, three invitations and four waves you'll produce 3 x 4 = 12 rows. Then you try to muddle through somehow to get the counts you want.
Instead of joining the invitations and waves to an event, join the invitation count and the wave count to an event. In other words: aggregate before joining.
WITH
  event_invitations AS
  (
    SELECT
      event_id,
      COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM invitations
    GROUP BY event_id
  ),
  event_waves AS
  (
    SELECT
      wavable_id AS event_id,
      COUNT(*) AS total,
      COUNT(scheduled_at) AS scheduled
    FROM waves
    WHERE wavable_type = 'Event'
    GROUP BY wavable_id
  )
SELECT
  e.*,
  COALESCE(i.total, 0) AS total_invitation_count,
  COALESCE(w.total, 0) AS total_wave_count,
  COALESCE(w.scheduled, 0) AS scheduled_wave_count
FROM events e
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_invitations i ON i.event_id = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_waves w ON w.event_id = e.id
ORDER BY e.id;


count(scheduled_at) although that line might be a good excuse to introduce the filter clause to OP since they keep using conditional aggregates.

@Zegarek: You are right, of course. I made this more complicated than need be. Thank you.

This was really helpful, thank you @ThorstenKettner
I finally managed to do it with an hybrid version of several answers. I'll post it but I'll check your answer, it was the closest! ❤️

The following SQL creates the tables and populates them with test values to verify that the query is producing the intended results. The event names are the expected counts for invitations, validated invitations, waves, and scheduled waves.
CREATE TABLE events (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UUID UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () NOT NULL,
  name CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE invitations (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UUID UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () NOT NULL,
  event_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES events (id),
  status INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE invitation_waves (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UUID UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () NOT NULL,
  name CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  wavable_type CHARACTER VARYING,
  wavable_id BIGINT,
  scheduled_at TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO
  events (id, name)
VALUES
  (1, '0 0 0 0'),
  (2, '1 0 0 0'),
  (3, '2 1 0 0'),
  (4, '0 0 1 0'),
  (5, '0 0 2 1'),
  (6, '1 0 1 0'),
  (7, '2 1 1 0'),
  (8, '1 0 2 1'),
  (9, '2 1 2 1');

INSERT INTO
  invitations (id, event_id, status)
VALUES
  (1, 2, 0),
  (2, 3, 0),
  (3, 3, 4),
  (4, 6, 0),
  (5, 7, 0),
  (6, 7, 5),
  (7, 8, 0),
  (8, 9, 0),
  (9, 9, 6);

INSERT INTO
  invitation_waves (id, name, wavable_type, wavable_id, scheduled_at)
VALUES
  (1, 'wave1', 'Event', 4, NULL),
  (2, 'wave2', 'Event', 5, NULL),
  (3, 'wave3', 'Event', 5, '2024-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP),
  (4, 'wave4', 'Event', 6, NULL),
  (5, 'wave5', 'Event', 7, NULL),
  (6, 'wave6', 'Event', 8, NULL),
  (7, 'wave7', 'Event', 8, '2024-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP),
  (8, 'wave8', 'Event', 9, NULL),
  (9, 'wave9', 'Event', 9, '2024-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP);

The following demonstrates using COUNT(DISTINCT ...) FILTER (WHERE ...) to report counts for multiple conditions within a single query. Without DISTINCT, the query would report incorrect counts for events that have both invitations and waves when either has more than one associated with the event.
SELECT
  e.id AS event_id,
  e.name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) AS total_invitations,
  COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) FILTER (WHERE i.status IN (4, 5, 6)) AS total_validated,
  COUNT(DISTINCT w.id) AS total_waves,
  COUNT(DISTINCT w.id) FILTER (WHERE w.scheduled_at IS NOT NULL) AS scheduled_waves
FROM
  events e
  LEFT JOIN invitations i
    ON i.event_id = e.id
  LEFT JOIN invitation_waves w
    ON w.wavable_type = 'Event' AND
       w.wavable_id = e.id
GROUP BY
  e.id
ORDER BY
  e.id;

Running the query with the test data produces the following results:



event_id
name
total_invitations
total_validated
total_waves
scheduled_waves




1
0 0 0 0
0
0
0
0


2
1 0 0 0
1
0
0
0


3
2 1 0 0
2
1
0
0


4
0 0 1 0
0
0
1
0


5
0 0 2 1
0
0
2
1


6
1 0 1 0
1
0
1
0


7
2 1 1 0
2
1
1
0


8
1 0 2 1
1
0
2
1


9
2 1 2 1
2
1
2
1



